# How can I remove a non-steam game from family view?

Tags: steam

For Steam games, there is the option to remove the game from family view via the context menu.

After adding a non-Steam game, the game is visible in family view. 
And there seems to be no way to select that option.

The [Steam online help sites](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_cat.php?id=103) remain silent about this.

Any hints on this?